# How to write infinite series in expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series: $$1+ (1*2)/(1*3) +(1*2*3)/(1*3*5) +...$$
The question is: how to write this sam as expression of form
 $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$?

Of course, the numerator is of the form n!. But how can we express the denominator? It seems like a factorial over one term.

Comment: The $n$th term is $$\dfrac{2^n}{\binom{2n}n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [double factorial](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Double_factorial) to write
$$a_n = \frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!} = \frac{n!}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}}=\frac{2^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your denominator is the [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). There are various ways to re-express it using other operators. For example you can think of it as the product of all numbers from $1$ to $2n$ divided by just the even terms. In mathematical terms:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\times n!}$$